# Function with derived arguments in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class A {
};

class B : public A {
};

class C : public A {
};

class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void dummy(A* a) = 0;
};

class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
public:
    void dummy(B* b);
};

class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass {
public:
    void dummy(C* c);
};
```

As you see `B` and `C` inherit from `A` and `DerivedClass1` and `DerivedClass2` inherit from `BaseClass`.

Due to my understanding this kind of declaration of function `dummy()` is not allowed, since the arguments have changed, even though `B` and `C` are derived from `A`.

What is the correct way to do it?

A possibility would be to leave the arguments as they're used to be in the `BaseClass` and just do casting afterwards within the `dummy` function, but I guess this isn't really nice.

Otherwise, just do no derivation of `dummy` (and remove it from `BaseClass`), so both classes `DerivedClass1` and `DerivedClass2` declare them independently. But then the idea of all classes derived from `BaseClass` have to implement dummy goes lost.

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: That's not what inheritance is for. If you have `BaseClass*` somewhere and you want to call `dummy`, how do you know what argument should you pass? `A*`? `B*`? `C*`? You should rethink your design.

Comment: `dummy()` in `DerivedClass1` and `DerivedClass2` are overloads (and they are allowed). A `void dummy(A*);` would `override`.

Comment: Considering design for what I see: I think it would be better, if base class implements a member of `A` and the derived class create there corresponding type. Dummy is then called without parameter and can do the stuff needed. Maybe, if you give more details, we can discuss about a "good" solution

Comment: I made an example of what the effect would be if you made your `DerivedClass`es concrete (instead of abstract as they are now): [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qU2Zbq)

Comment: Couldn't this be solved by making `BaseClass` a template where `A` is a template type argument? (Granted, you'd have to use C++2x to allow the use of type argument constraints if you want to ensure that `T : A`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when declaring that something `A` is a base class of `B` or `C`, you do so with the intent that `B` and `C` have all the properties of `A` and that you can use `B` and `C` in any place that you can use `A` in. A good design often provides a meaningful definition of `A` that allows for a generic definition of `dummy` for all specializations of `A`. In that sense, the problem might be less common than you may expect.

If you want to instantiate `DerivedClass1` or `DerivedClass2`, your notion of `DerivedClass1` and `DerivedClass2` does not really make sense, because in order to *be* a `BaseClass`, they have to provide a meaningful definition of `void dummy(A *a)`. You have to provide that definition. They may provide *additional* methods `void dummy(B *b)` or `void dummy(C *c)`, but those are only used if the static type of the `BaseClass` implementation is either `DerivedClass1` or `DerivedClass2`.

If `DerivedClass1` or `DerivedClass2` need to distinguish between `B` and `C`, this might be a sign of bad design. But it might be a well-informed decision as well. Generally, you need a way to dynamically dispatch to the right method. For example, this could be achieved like this:

```
class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass
{
    virtual void dummy( A * a ) override {
        if( dynamic_cast<B*>( a ) != nullptr ) {
            dummy( dynamic_cast<B*>( a );
        }
        else if( dynamic_cast<C*>( a ) != nullptr) {
            dummy( dynamic_cast<C*>( a );
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    void dummy( B * );
    void dummy( C * );
};
```

Comment: classes deriving from an abstract class often do implement pure virtuals but by no means they are required to do so. Your second paragraph suggests that this would be the case.

Comment: @idclev463035818 pure-virtual functions **are** required to be overridden in a non-abstract subclass. I think people are downvoting Markus on a technicality.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Also, `463035818` isn't a valid IDCLEV map number :P

Comment: @Dai on a non-abstract subclass yes, but that is not what is written on that second paragraph. I dont know why others vote, I just pointed to something that I think is misinformation

Comment: @Dai did you try it?

Comment: @idclev463035818 You are right, of course. I made the assumption that OP wanted to instantiate DerivedClass1 or 2 and those were meant to be non-abstract. Edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I tried it in an unofficial webassembly port of Doom 2 and nothing happened :(

Comment: @Dai what a pitty :P. I am not happy about the space in my nick, because afair for the cheat to work there was no space allowed, but i didnt want to change it anymore when I realized it. Sorry for going a bit offtopic...

Answer (score 0):

> Due to my understanding this kind of declaration of function dummy() is not allowed

Technically the shown declarations of `dummy` are allowed. It may however be that you were hoping for the children to be concrete which is not the case.

> Otherwise, just do no derivation of dummy (and remove it from BaseClass), so both classes DerivedClass1 and DerivedClass2 declare them independently.

This approach makes sense.

> But then the idea of all classes derived from BaseClass have to implement dummy goes lost.

This is simply an idea that cannot be expressed with inheriting a base class. There is no concept of "child implements a member function with *some* argument". The argument type must be known, and all children must accept all arguments that the base accepts. And that is not fulfilled by your hierarchy, so the children remain abstract.

The structure that you are looking for instead seems to be *concept*. C++20 will introduce a programmatic way of specifying concepts; until then concepts are implicit: If you write a template, you can specify that a type argument must satisfy the requirement of having a member function `dummy`. Both of the "derived" types would satisfy that concept.

Answer (score 0):

The point of virtual inheritance is that you can call your derived classes through a reference/pointer to the base type:

```
BaseClass* p = some_factory();
```

Hence when calling `p.dummy(...)` you don't (necessarily) know what runtime type is sitting behind the pointer. So you cannot sensibly decide whether you have to pass it an `A`, `B`, or `C` instance.

That's why you have to match the declaration type and figure out inside your overriding function what actual object you have. Depending on the context, perhaps a

- `static_cast`: if you know for sure that the caller will pass you the correct runtime type
- `dynamic_cast`: if you don't, but this incurs runtime costs and requries rtti
- **or** your `A` type has virtual member functions that you can simply call through your `A*` argument

For instance:

```
void DerivedClass1::dummy(A* a) {
  if (B* const b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a)) {
    /* do stuff with b */
  } else {
    /* error handling -> wrong runtime type */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not able to handle your situation because there is no way to put such a constraint on function calls by the base class. But changing the type of a virtual function can be done for instance for returned types, see [covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)):

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void dosomething(A*) = 0;
    virtual A* dummy(A*) = 0;
};

class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
public:
    void dosomething(A* a) {B* b = dummy(a); do something;}
    //See return type was A* but now is B*
    B* dummy(A* a) { return dynamic_cast<B*>(a); }
};
```